# How to configure my ubuntu to allow me send multicast through eth0 address, and receive through eth1 address?

Tags: networking

How to configure my ubuntu to allow me send multicast through eth0 address, and receive through eth1 address? I am able to send and receive through the same address, but failed when sending through 192.168.122.140 (eth0), and receiving from 192.168.122.40 (eth1).

**Details**:

I wrote two programs 1) a multicast sender that broadcast message through interface 192.168.122.140 with a multicast address and port 2) a multicast receiver that receive multicast message through interface 192.168.122.40 and point to the address and port defined at sender application.

I have tested the sender and receiver applications with both having the same interface 192.168.122.**140**, **or** 192.168.122.**40**, receiver is able to receive packet from the sender application. but when I set 192.168.122.**140** to the sender, and set 192.168.122.**40** to the receiver, the receiver receive nothing.

This is what my route table look like. If it is wrong, please help correct it.

```html
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         hkcore.hk.abc.n 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth1
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
224.0.0.0       *               240.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0
```

```html
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d0:2b:2c:06:23  
          inet addr:192.168.122.140  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::76d0:2bff:fe2c:623/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:109471 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1513722 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29824161 (29.8 MB)  TX bytes:1186271256 (1.1 GB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7200000-f7220000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:21:25:05:13  
          inet addr:192.168.122.40  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 Memory:f71c0000-f71e0000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:406555 (406.5 KB)  TX bytes:406555 (406.5 KB)
```

Comment: First of all, can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?  Secondly, what is failing?  What are you doing to try to receive multicast packets through `eth1`?  It appears that your `eth0` and `eth1` are on the same local network segment.  Are you trying to receive (through `eth1`) the packets that you send (through `eth0`)?  If not, are there multicast packets on that network segment coming from elsewhere?  Are you receiving them?

Comment: Have just added more detail on the post. Yes, I am trying to receive (through eth1) the packets that I send (through eth0).